# how to use jquery to do a gridview.row.count and change a labels text to the row count

Tags: .net, jquery, vb.net

Basically, Is it possible to get a grids row count using jquery.

if my grid has 20 rows in it not including the header or footer, i want to now the count of actual rows, this will tell my users how many tasks they have in their list.

Since, my page uses tabs i want the user to be able to see the count of each grid in its respective tab. each tab has a label and i want that label to have the number of rows.

Comment: Restating the "question title" as the first line of the actual question is useless, btw. Also, this needs more information (show some sample code, what you'd like to see as result, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery:

```
$("tr").length();
```

This will return the number of table rows on a given page. Of course, you could be more specific by passing a DOM id or a class to count. If you provide the markup in question, I could help you get it right.

Comment: suppose i wanted the row count for gridview1,  and wanted to place the text in label1

Comment: o actually they are in seperate divs, called tab1, tab2,tab3

Comment: What is gridview1? Is it the id of the table that contains the rows you would like counted? It would be helpful to see your HTML.

Comment: yes gridview1 is the id of the gridview whose row count i need

Comment: and label1 is the label name of the label whose text i want changed

Comment: To count the rows of a table (id="gridview1") and put the value in an input field (name=label1), you could use this jquery code: $("input[name='label1']").text($("#gridview1 tr").length)
edit: lol - just noticed your convo with Jamie. Sorry. :)

Comment: hmm for some reason my labels text is still not changing

Comment: I'm going to need to see your HTML to help you any further.

Answer (score 0):

If each of your rows has a class then you can use jquery's length attribute to count how many rows there are

[Here's an example (i've used divs)](http://jsfiddle.net/9nctR/)

```
<div class="test">Test 1</div>

<div class="test">Test 2</div>

<div class="label">fdgdfg</div>
```

And the jquery

```
$('.label').text($('.test').length)
```

**EDIT**

To do this for rows within a div

```
$('.label').text($('div.test tr').length)

<div class="test">

<table>

<tr><td>something</td></tr>

<tr><td>something else</td></tr>

</table>

</div>
```

By rows I assume you mean `tr`

[Here's an updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9nctR/1/)

Comment: how can i do this for rows in a certain div

Comment: <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.label6').text($('div.tab1 > tr').length)
});
</script>

Comment: @MyHeadeHurts - we do need to see some HTML to help you anymore

Comment: @MyHeadHurts - you need to look at your rendered code and post some for us to see and then we can try and help more :)

Answer (score 0):

var rowsCount = $("#<%=GridView.ClientID %> tr").length;