# Setting Label Text to Number of Rows with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

This is my code but nothing happens.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var totalRows = $("#<%=GridView3.ClientID %> tr").length;
  document.getElementById('Label6').InnerHTML = totalRows;
});
```

this is what i ended up using

```
var rqnum = $("#<%=GridView3.ClientID %> tr").length - 1;
document.getElementById('rqnum').innerHTML = rqnum;

var oknum = $("#<%=GridView4.ClientID %> tr").length - 1;
document.getElementById('oknum').innerHTML = oknum;

var xlnum = $("#<%=GridView5.ClientID %> tr").length - 1;
document.getElementById('xlnum').innerHTML = xlnum;

var dynum = $("#<%=datalist1.ClientID %> tr").length / 3;
document.getElementById('dynum').innerHTML = dynum;
```

**this way it subtracts the header, however, how can i make it so if it is 0 dont subtract the -1 because i dont want negatives**

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045580/how-to-use-jquery-to-do-a-gridview-row-count-and-change-a-labels-text-to-the-row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery, I believe you should be able to set it this way:

```
$("#Label6").html(totalRows);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `.innerHTML` rather than `.InnerHTML`. Make sure to always use the proper case.

Also, since you're working with jQuery you could ignore the `.innerHTML` and simply set the value of `#Label6` using either `$.html()` or `$.text()`.

Lastly, be sure that `<%=GridView3.ClientID %>` is producing the output that you are expecting.

*Updates following question in comment*

If you would like to ignore your table headers, you could count only the `tr` elements within the `tbody` tag:

```
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Column 1</td>
      <td>Column 2</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Foo</td>
      <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>
  $(function(){
    $("#Label6").text( $("#myTable tbody tr").length );
  });
</script>
```

Preventing a negative number is fairly simple as well. You could use a ternary operator to do this:

```
var numRows = ( numRows < 0 ) ? 0 : numRows ;
```

Perform this logic before using the `numRows` variable and it will prevent any negative number from showing up. The lowest number to show will be 0.

Comment: it worked but i had to subtract -1 to remove the header from the count, but if theres no rows or a header i get -1 how can i not subtract when 0

Answer (score 1):

It is `innerHTML`.

or if you want to use jquery you can simply do this:

```
$("#Label6").text(totalRows);
```